# Kqueue returning both EVFILT_READ and EVFILT_WRITE but I installed separate (ident,filt) pairs

Tags: c, kqueue

I'm running into an issue that I'm not sure if is expected behavior from kqueue or if it's something I'm doing wrong.

I need to install separate events with kqueue for a single socket file descriptor. The separate events are one for (sockfd,EVFILT_READ) and (sockfd,EVFILT_WRITE). However when I pull events out of kqueue later I get two events from kqueue, but both events contain (event.filter & EVFILT_READ) and (event.filter & EVFILT_WRITE).

I need them to be separate otherwise I don't know which event actually is ready, read or write?

Here's some sample code I put together to illustrate the issue. Please keep in mind this is just test code to figure out why I'm getting both filter flags in each event.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    //listening_sockfd = setup listening socket

    //setup kqueue and vars
    int kq = kqueue();
    int res = 0;
    int bufres = 0;
    struct timespec ts = {0};
    struct timespec * tsp = &ts;
    struct kevent ke2[2];

    //install read for listening socket
    struct kevent ke1;
    bzero(&ke1,sizeof(ke1));
    ke1.ident = listening_sockfd;
    ke1.flags = EV_ADD;
    ke1.filter = EVFILT_READ;
    res = kevent(kq,&ke1,1,NULL,0,tsp);

    while(1) {
        new_client:

        //wait for a client to connect
        res = kevent(kq,NULL,0,&ke1,1,NULL);
        if(res < 0) printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));

        if(res > 0) {
            //accept the client
            int clientfd = accept(skinfo.sockfd,NULL,NULL);

            //install read events for client
            bzero(&ke1,sizeof(ke1));
            ke1.ident = clientfd;
            ke1.flags = EV_ADD;
            ke1.filter = EVFILT_READ;
            res = kevent(kq,&ke1,1,NULL,0,tsp);
            if(res < 0) printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

            while(1) {

                //wait for readable content from the client
                bzero(&ke1,sizeof(ke1));
                res = kevent(kq,NULL,0,&ke1,1,NULL);
                if(res < 0) printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

                if(res > 0) {

                    //check for client disconnect
                    if(ke1.flags & EV_EOF) {
                        close(clientfd);
                        goto new_client;
                    }

                    //now install write events for client
                    bzero(&ke1,sizeof(ke1));
                    ke1.ident = clientfd;
                    ke1.flags = EV_ADD;
                    ke1.filter = EVFILT_WRITE;
                    res = kevent(kq,&ke1,1,NULL,0,tsp);
                    if(res < 0) printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

                    //now wait for it to be writable - this will return
                    //immediately because the socket is writable.
                    res = kevent(kq,NULL,0,ke2,2,NULL);
                    if(res < 0) printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

                    if(res >= 0) {
                        char buf[128];
                        printf("res: %i\n",res);

                        //we have two events from kqueue because I installed
                        //two (ident,filter) pairs.
                        int i = 0;
                        for(i; i<2; i++) {
                            printf("ident: %i\n",ke2[i].ident);
                            printf("filter[%i] %lu\n",i,ke2[i].filter);
                            printf("data: %lu\n",ke2[i].data);

                            //QUESTION: Why does EVFILT_READ && EVFILT_WRITE come
                            //back in the same event when I installed two seperate
                            //(ident,filter) pairs?
                            if(ke2[i].filter & EVFILT_READ) printf("EVFILT_READ\n");
                            if(ke2[i].filter & EVFILT_WRITE) printf("EVFILT_WRITE\n");

                            if(ke2[i].filter & EVFILT_READ) {
                                printf("readable!\n");
                                bufres = read(clientfd,buf,128);
                            }

                            if(ke2[i].filter & EVFILT_WRITE) {
                                printf("writable\n");

                                //shut off write events to stop infinite loop
                                //because the socket is writable
                                bzero(&ke1,sizeof(ke1));
                                ke1.ident = clientfd;
                                ke1.flags = EV_DELETE;
                                ke1.filter = EVFILT_WRITE;
                                res = kevent(kq,&ke1,1,NULL,0,tsp);

                                write(clientfd,buf,bufres);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to figure this out. Why does each kqueue event contain both EVFILT_READ and EVFILT_WRITE when I installed separate events?

The real issue this is creating for me is that because these events always report EVFILT_READ, it has the side-effects of the code always thinking there's a read available, but there's really not, so a call to read() will be unsuccessful and have other consequences. Note that this code doesn't show those consequences, this is just a sample of the issue I wrote so I figure this out and continue with my real code.

Any ideas?

PS Here's output from the printf:

```
res: 2
ident: 5
filter[0] 4294967295
data: 5
EVFILT_READ
EVFILT_WRITE
readable!
writable
ident: 5
filter[1] 4294967294
data: 146988
EVFILT_READ
EVFILT_WRITE
readable!
writable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AH! I think I figured it out. What kqueue documentation doesn't say is that event.filter doesn't contain bit flags. So I need to check for read/write with event.filter == EVFILT_READ, event.filter == EVFILT_WRITE.

Comment: Yes, hit exactly the same sort of issue *sigh*.

Comment: Another victim of the same design issue reporting.

Answer (score 6):

As you noticed, they are not bits to be tested.

Consulting the header on OS X, we find

```
#define EVFILT_READ             (-1)
#define EVFILT_WRITE            (-2)
```

Since `-1` is all 1-bits, `x & EVFILT_READ` will be true for any nonzero `x`, and `x & EVFILT_WRITE` will be true for `x` not equal to zero or one.